# Reference request: Euler's 36 officer problem

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, reference-request, latin-square

I am recently reading MacNeish's 1922 paper ["Euler Squares,"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967920?origin=crossref) in which he mentions that [Euler's 36 officer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares#Thirty-six_officers_problem) has been proven first by Tarry in 1901 via analyzing all possible cases. However, MacNeish then wrote on page 1 that

> A geometric proof by methods of [Analysis Situs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_Situs_(paper)) has been given by J. Petersen (Annuaire des Mathématiciens, 1901-02, pp. 413-426).

so I wonder whether there are any English publications that explain Peterson's solution of Euler's 36 officer problem.

Comment: I found the original paper in French. Is that acceptable? Maybe you could read it with some translation tool. Btw may I ask why you wanna to read Petersen's paper? According Knuth's *The art of computer programming V4* chapter 1,  there is some flaw in Petersen's proof.

Comment: @onriv so is it that no proofs other than brute-force approach is available?

Answer (score 2):

I saw the original paper of Petersen in http://prosopomaths.ahp-numerique.fr/annuaire-laisant, but it's in French.

Knuth says [https://www.math.uci.edu/~brusso/[14]BosShrParCJM1960.pdf](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ebrusso/%5B14%5DBosShrParCJM1960.pdf) this is the first rigorous proof. It's too long for a comment. I updated it as an answer. I don't know if Bose, etc's proof is brute-force approach or not. But I'am wondering what's the "flaw" in Petersen's proof.

And the following references is quoted from Knuth's *The art of computer programming* Volume 4, Chapter 1, page 7:

> Euler’s conjecture about the remaining cases n = 10, n = 14, ... was
> “proved” three times, by J. Petersen [Annuaire des mathématiciens (Paris: 1902),
> 413–427], by P. Wernicke [Jahresbericht der Deutschen Math.-Vereinigung 19
> (1910), 264–267], and by H. F. MacNeish [Annals of Math. (2) 23 (1922), 221–
> 227]. Flaws in all three arguments became known, however; and the question
> was still unsettled when computers became available many years later. One of
> the very first combinatorial problems to be tackled by machine was therefore the
> enigma of 10 × 10 Græco-Latin squares: Do they exist or not?
>
> In 1957, L. J. Paige and C. B. Tompkins programmed the SWAC computer to
> search for a counterexample to Euler’s prediction. They selected one particular
> 10×10 latin square “almost at random,” and their program tried to find another
> square that would be orthogonal to it. But the results were discouraging, and
> they decided to shut the machine off after five hours. Already the program
> had generated enough data for them to predict that at least 4.8 × 10 11 hours of
> computer time would be needed to finish the run!
>
> Shortly afterwards, three mathematicians made a breakthrough that put
> latin squares onto page one of major world newspapers: R. C. Bose, S. S. Shri-
> khande, and E. T. Parker found a remarkable series of constructions that yield
> orthogonal n×n squares for all n > 6 [Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. 45 (1959), 734–737,
> 859–862; Canadian J. Math. 12 (1960), 189–203]. Thus, after resisting attacks
> for 180 years, Euler’s conjecture turned out to be almost entirely wrong.
>
> Their discovery was made without computer help. But Parker worked for
> UNIVAC , and he soon brought programming skills into the picture by solving the
> problem of Paige and Tompkins in less than an hour, on a UNIVAC 1206 Military
> Computer. [See Proc. Symp. Applied Math. 10 (1960), 71–83; 15 (1963), 73–81.]

Comment: What you quote is talking about Euler's conjecture, which is a different problem from what I am asking. In the language of your text, I am looking for a proof for the nonexistence for $n=6$.

Comment: and I am aware of Bose, Shirkhande, and Parker's work. What they did is to refute the conjecture of nonexistence when $n=10,14,...$

Comment: Considering that solutions exist for $n=10$ and $n=14$ (called "Euler Spoilers") I doubt that there is a proof of the non-existence for $n=6$ without exhaustive search. This question has , by the way , been already asked here (perhaps someone finds the target)

Comment: @TravorLZH Oh, you are right. I'm sorry for misunderstanding your meaning

Comment: @Peter I guess it can somehow be converted to a graph problem, and this is why I tag this in the question.